# skrollr plugin to convert colors

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb, hsl

I'm trying to write a plugin for [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to allow transitions between different kinds of colors annotations.

This is the code at the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/nL75k/

It should run before skrollr and convert every color annotation to HSLA.

I don't understand why the console gives me 3 times the same results:

```
background-color:hsla(56,100,50,  1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 0.5); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(56,100,50,  1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 0.5); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(56,100,50,  1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 0.5); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
```

It should be:

```
background-color:hsla(56,100,50,  1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 0.5); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
background-color:hsla(0,100,50, 1); fiddle.jshell.net/nL75k/show/:117
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getAllDataElements` you are iterating over all elements and then over all attributes. But for each data attribute you're adding the elements to `matches`. The div has three data attribute, which causes it to be added three times.

Simple fix: break the loop

```
//check if attibute name starts with "data-"
if (attr.indexOf("data-") == 0) {
    matches.push(element); //add it to matches
    break;
}
```